The positive/negative sign in inner product involve diagonal matrix and basis transformation matrix.
The expression of one inner product is $<\pi PDEP^{-1}, \pi PD^2EP^{-1}>$.
Here, $\pi$ is a row vector that has strictly non-negative terms, D is a diagonal matrix with non-positive diagonal elements and E is a diagonal matrix with non-negative diagonal elements. P is a basis transformation matrix, its columns are the eigenvalue of a matrix.
I think that $<\pi PDEP^{-1}, \pi PD^2EP^{-1}>$ should always be non-positive, but I don't know how to prove it, especially how P and $P^{-1}$ impact the sign of final scalar or why it does not impact the sign of final scalar.
Thank you.
